# How to remove hand icon (Stop Draw icon) in Drawing Manager?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, draw

I need to remove the hand icon (Stop Draw icon) from Drawing Manager tool and keep only polygon in drawing manager.

I tried:

```
drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
drawingControl: false
```

It disables the Drawing Manager toolbar, but can draw polygons. 
My requirement is to show only polygon in the Drawing Manager toolbar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got the Answer,

In `CSS` give,

```
div[title="Stop drawing"] { 
    display: none !important; 
}
```

now the hand icon will not shown

Comment: @MarkosEvlogimenos: It really depends on your requirement. My requirement was not for localized maps. Please do a research and then downvote. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This has been changed to

```
button[title='Stop drawing'] {
        display: none !important;
}
```

sometime around October 2020.